# Creating Postman JSON Collection File

Tags: c#, json, api, postman

There are two e-Trade Service Companies I work with, both integrate their clients to their services with JSON API for POST/GET/PUT actions, as below script:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "barcode": "BARCODE-01234",
      "title": "BABY SKIRT",
      ...................
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://www.myadress/path/folder/image_01.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attributeId": 338,
          "attributeValueId": 6980
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

One of e-Trade company supply also a file called "XYZ-Collection.txt", which includes code below (partly showed):

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "65747u-67b78-78de-7881c-e887e5c",
        "name": "Catalog Integration",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get All Categories",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "basic": [
                        {
                            "key": "password",
                            "value": "",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "username",
                            "value": "****_dev",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
```

I am using this file to automate my integration with C#, getting parameters and their type of values from this file, it is very usefull (WSDL and OPEN API has already these files).

But other e-Trade company does not supply this file, my question is:

How can I produce this file from any JSON Code they supply to me, for example url like below:

```
https://api.etradecompany.com/sapigw/suppliers/{supplierid}/v2/products
```

Comment: You can't generate a Postman collection unless you have all of the data, in which case you create it by hand - there's no "generation"

Comment: they supply Parameter, Description and Data Type in a list, would it be enough to generate, and do I have to install POSTMAN also, if yes can you guide me, thanks...

Comment: Can you provide an example of the list please? Do you just want to have the URL, description and query string filled out?

Comment: basically I need Collection File only to parse with C# code and to provide user a `Data Entry Form`, due to security agreement I can not provide same data, could you please give a similar teaching link to complete such steps...

Comment: If the api support swagger or othe open api based documentation, just import from URL on postman and supply this URL: http://domain/swagger/v1/swagger.json. this Will create a New collection with all the endpoints for you. If they dont support open api, there is no way other than creating the collection manually.

Comment: do I have to install POSTMAN or there is online tools, thanks...

Comment: @MestreDosMagros I have showed `_postman_id´ in my sample script, would it be helpful for your question